# Rating Score: Should a user be allowed to rate as many times as he wants, and how to deal with that score?

Tags: ratings, nps

I'm new to UX and just trying to make sure I ask the UX community for help on questions like this:

I'm working on a product that has a rate us functionality for NPS score. I'm wondering if

A - user should be allowed to rate again (elaboration - User has given 1 rating, and then goes back after some period of time and rates again)

B - How to cater for this score. Should I overwrite the previous rating response and only count their new rating. Or should I average their rating and make that count into NPS. Or should I consider this new rating as a new response (almost as if from a new user) and take that into account for NPS?

I would really appreciate some help as I'm a little stuck here.

Thank you

Comment: It depends on why people rate again and after how much time or experiences. The user gained more or a different experience with the product with a reason. The answer depends on that reason. Also, maybe he/she is already taking the previous experience into account: Can you show them their previous ratings and/or feedback?

Comment: @jazZRo We do not show them their previous ratings. So let's say that you do let them rate again after some time - Would you count the new rating as an overwrite, or would you count it as a new independent entry, or would you average the previous and new rating and incorporate that?

Answer (score 2):

The answers would depend on if the rating is for a product or a service.

Ex. If the rating is for a service like a hotel stay, then perhaps the user has visited the hotel mutiple times and would like to allot different ratings. Logically collecting mutiple rating would help both the business as well as the consumers looking at the ratings, as this is allow you to average out the two ratings instead of having only one or even show the separate rating if its possible.
This is probably the use case where users are most likely to change ratings rather than on a product.

If its for a product, it is less likely for the user to have many different ratings and also more usesful for the business to allow only one rating.
Ideally,the user should be allowed to change the rating at a later time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks - I think we're steering in this direction as well. To essentially only get them to give this rating at one point. Currently we had put rate us in the menu and they could essentially rate as many times as they wanted (and it wouldn't show previous rating - just a clean rating form). I'm just thinking about how to fix this.